# How to add org.apache.commons.logging to Eclipse RCP Target Definition

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, apache-commons-logging, target-platform

When I set "Running Platform" as the Target Platform for my Eclipse e4 RCP application everything works fine.
Now, I want to provide a common **target definition** for the development team. The issue is that **org.apache.commons.logging** is a required bundle in one of my MANIFEST files.

**Apparently this bundle cannot be found in any of the Software Site Locations that I use in my target definition.**

As I don't have enough reputation to post images I'll give you the picpaste-link instead. The image shows my current target definition. http://picpaste.com/target-2BtZ4nMj.PNG (I'll update the post with the correct image as soon as possible.)

Is there an update site that can provide the Apache bundle. I see the plug-in/bundle in my local Eclipse installation, I just don't know where it came from, such that I could use it in my custom target platform definition.

Comment: I think it comes with eclipse installation. Do you have any error with the plugin requiring it ? Generally I add this plugin to a feature, then the feature to the product definition and don't have any problem

Comment: @flafoux We're using the Nebula Nattable which has the dependency to Apache Logging. Is there a way to add the bundle JAR file to the feature, such that Nattable won't complain?
When I click on "Add..." in the feature editor it only shows me a list of plug-ins that I have in the target platform, where Apache Logging doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you using for your target platform?

Comment: @greg-449 I added a screenshot of the current target definition to the question.

Comment: I think the Eclipse RCP SDK should contain the logging plugin. Look at the 'Contents' tab of the Target Platform and check it is there and selected.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you greg! Your comment gave me the hint to a solution. In fact, Eclipse RCP SDK does not contain the logging plugin, but the Eclipse Platform SDK does. Is that considered bad practice to use the Platform SDK when all you need is the RCP SDK plus logging?

Comment: Should be OK but be sure to only select the things you want, a lot of those plugins are not suitable for e4

Comment: Thank you so much. Mind to add an answer to this question, such that I can accept it?